# Scala/Java syntax, return interface implementation

Tags: java, scala

What does this line of code mean in the code at the bottom?

```
return Promise.<SimpleResult>pure  //why is the dot
```

I am new to Scala and Java 6, what is the related topic/terminology?

If the framework doesn’t find an action method for a request, the onHandlerNotFound 
operation will be called:

```
import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.mvc.Http.*;
import play.libs.F.*;

import static play.mvc.Results.*;

public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    public Promise<SimpleResult> onHandlerNotFound(RequestHeader request) {
        return Promise.<SimpleResult>pure(notFound(
            views.html.notFoundPage.render(request.uri())
        ));
    }
```

}

**Update**:

`play.libs.F.Java` file

```
public static class Promise<A> {

    public static <A> Promise<A> pure(final A a) {
        return FPromiseHelper.pure(a);
    }
}
```

What is `<A>` and `Promise<A>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Promise.pure()` is a generic method, parameterized with some type T.

`Promise.<SimpleResult>pure()` calls this method with SimpleResult as the generic type. Most of the time, doing it is optional because the compiler infers the generic type from the arguments of the method or from the type of the variable the result is assigned to, like in

```
List<String> s = Collections.emptyList();
```

which is a shortcut for

```
List<String> s = Collections.<String>emptyList();
```

or

```
Set<String> Collections.singleton("hello");
```

which is a shortcut for

```
Set<String> Collections.<String>singleton("hello");
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt and detailed explanation. I added an update for further explanation, could you please have a look?

Comment: A is the generic type. Promise<A> is what is returned by the generic method. If you call it with a String, you'll get a Promise<String>. If you call it with an Integer, you'll get a Promise<Integer>. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes type inference system can't fully serve its purpose and fails to automatically deduce the return type of the call of the generic method. To specify such a type, this construct exists - you help to infer the correct type of the expression.

Look at [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.11) for more. ([Formal definition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12))

Comment: Thanks for the prompt explanation and the links!